# Is question about security aspect of VM in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

Shouldn't [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/795/limitations-of-stack-inspection) question about security aspect of Virtual Machine on CS.SE migrated on this site? While it is barely in the scope of CS, I have a guess that this will better suit to Security.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the scope of that question actually fits CS.SE as the question itself is:

> What are the limitations of stack inspection? What mechanisms have
>   been proposed to replace it? Have any significant changes been made to
>   the model since it was introduced in the late 90s?

but you can always flag for them to have a look, if they don't want it we could look at it.